# permutations and composites of transpositions

Tags: linear-algebra

When writing a permutation as a composite of transpositions, do you include elements that are mapped to themselves?
e.g.$ 1\rightarrow2 $ , $2\rightarrow3 $ ,   $3\rightarrow 1$ , $4\rightarrow 4$
would this be $(1,2)(2,3)$ or $(1,2)(2,3)(4)?$

Comment: You may choose to include or to not include one-cycles as every one-cycle is merely the identity permutation.

Answer (score 1):

You can write it like $(1\, 2\, 3)(4)$ or only $(1\, 2\, 3)$.

Comment: isnt that cyclic form? id like to write it as a composition of transpositions to find whether its an odd or even permutation

Comment: Then you use it like your first: $(1\, 2)(2\, 3)$